# How to handle apostrophe, single quote and double quote at the same time?

Tags: javascript, urlhacking

I was trying to include a field value in windows.location of JavaScript which have combination of apostrophe, single quote and double quote. Is there any way I can handle this string combinations?

Comment: Can you provide an example string, & the code you tried using?

Comment: My sample field value is _'"Someone`s Name"'_. And I'm trying to solve this using encodeURI in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSENCODE to get it to proper JavaScript escaping, and then encodeURIComponent to make sure the URL is correct.

Example Code:

```
var someonesName = "{!JSENCODE(Contact.Name)}";
var someUrl = "https://.../?name="+encodeURIComponent(someonesName);
```